# How use localStorage for save selected text in new div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm a novice developer in javascript and I need help with the code.
The essence of the program:

1. The user selects the text.
2. Press the button.
3. The text is saved in a specific area.
4. When you reload the page / after closing the browser, the text
   should be stored in the local scope (I use localStorage).
5. The user enters the page and sees the same text that he saved.

Thank you in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p>text1</p>
    <p>text2</p>
    <p>text3</p>
  </div>
  <div id="sel">place for text</div>
  <button onclick="saveText();">Save</button>
  <script src="copy.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>

"use strict"

function getSelectionText() {
  var text = "";
  var activeEl = document.activeElement;
  var activeElTagName = activeEl ? activeEl.tagName.toLowerCase() : null;
  if (
    (activeElTagName == "textarea") || (activeElTagName == "input" &&
      /^(?:text|search|password|tel|url)$/i.test(activeEl.type)) &&
    (typeof activeEl.selectionStart == "number")
  ) {
    text = activeEl.value.slice(activeEl.selectionStart, activeEl.selectionEnd);
  } else if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  }
  return text;
};

var saveText = function() {
  var selectionText = getSelectionText();
  var selCopy = document.querySelector("#sel");
  var createDiv = document.createElement("div");
  createDiv.classList.add("copyDiv");
  selCopy.appendChild(createDiv);
  createDiv.innerHTML = selectionText;

  localStorage.setItem('getDiv', document.getElementsByClassName('copyDiv'));
  var score = localStorage.getItem('getDiv');
};
```

Comment: Just want to know... Why do you want the user to "Select" the text and then save it instead of typing it out in a specific textarea input?

Comment: What is the error you get by running the existing code?

Comment: Hello, this is necessary for the convenience of the user, since the pieces of text can be large and their number can reach eg 20-30 pieces.
Functional reminds of notes in books.

Comment: Ritik Saxena, there is no error, but the code itself works. That is, after rebooting the page, new divs are not saved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple method to add selected text to storage.

```
function saveText() {
    var text = getSelectionText();
    text = text.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "<br>"); // Preserve line breaks.
    if (localStorage.getItem("savedText") === null) {
        localStorage["savedText"] = "";
    }
    localStorage["savedText"] += "<br><br>" + text;

    showText();
}

function showText() {
    var innerDiv = "<div class=\"copyDiv\">";
    innerDiv += localStorage["savedText"];
    innerDiv += "</div>";
    document.getElementById("sel").innerHTML = innerDiv;
}

window.onload = function() {
    showText();
};
```

Comment: Thank you, this code works great.
One question, in my code there is the addition of div, into which all the copied code goes.
Tell me how this work out.

Comment: Thanks for the reactive response.
And the last question, I do not understand why in this case only the last selected text is saved?

Comment: I still have a couple of questions.
So I created all these records via localeStorage, but if I want to take and delete from one of the ten records some one.
While I get to delete only everything. Right now I'm working on a code that will generate an additional class to each "delete" button and then try to bind each button to the element. Is this the right way?
The second question that I had. The selected text is displayed only after the page is reloaded. How do I make it appear in real time, and not after reloading the page?
I updated all the code in the question itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can write window.onload method in which you can set content of div which has id 'sel' like

```
window.onload = function() {
 document.getElementById("sel").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem('getDiv');;
}
```